# Splitting a string on a space and removing empty entries

Tags: c#

I am splitting a string like this:

```
string[] elements = templine.Split
                            (space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

How can I get every element from `templine` except for `[1]` and assign it to   `string[] elements`?

Comment: @justin sorry not to be clear i just want to split that string, put it in the string array, but not include the second element

Comment: Thanks, I had misread your question at first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string[] elements = templine.Split(space).Where((s, i) => i != 1).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1! This is the only one that does what the OP wanted without fail.

Comment: @msarchet: I didn't say i *do*, just that I *try* :-)

Answer (score 3):

Lots of crazy LINQ examples here. This should probably be more efficient, if that matters to you:

```
public static T[] SkipElement<T>(this T[] source, int index)
{
    // Leaving out null/bounds checking for brevity.
    T[] array = new T[source.Length - 1];
    Array.Copy(source, 0, array, 0, index);
    Array.Copy(source, index + 1, array, index, source.Length - index - 1);
    return array;
}
```

With this you could do:

```
string[] elements = templine.Split(space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
elements = elements.SkipElement(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> elements = templine.Split
                                  (space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
                                 ToList().
                                 RemoveAt(1);
```

If you feel the need to go back to an array...

```
string[] elements = templine.Split
                                  (space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
                                 ToList().
                                 RemoveAt(1).
                                 ToArray();
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be RemoveAt(1)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Linq, you can probably do:

```
IEnumerable<string> elements = templine.Split(...).Take(1).Skip(1);
```

Comment: This will throw a compile time exception, you need to cast it to an array or have elements be IEnumerable.

Comment: It does not throw a compile time exception (this comment was after my edit), unless you are referring to my omitting the actual parameters, which I think a reasonably intelligent person would understand what I was getting at. Though I admit my solution is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq, you can just do

```
IEnumerable<String> elements = 
  empline.Split(space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
String[] result = 
 elements
 .Take(1)
 .Concat(elements
 .Skip(2))
 .ToArray();
```

Comment: (1) is the first element right? i need to skip the second one, [0] beign the first one right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could either ask your brother [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Or you could do something like this:

```
var elements = templine.Split(space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1).ToArray();
```

This will give you an array that contains all but the first element.  If you want the first, but not the second (as your question sort of suggests), you could do this:

```
var allElements = templine.Split(space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var someElements = allElements.Take(1).Concat(allElements.Skip(2)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Have to note that I did in fact laugh at the "Well, you could either ask you brother Jon" comment on this tail end of a Friday...

Comment: Well, I'm glad SOMEONE caught it!

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] elements = templine.Split
    (space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(s => s != "[1]").ToArray();
```

if you mean you'd like to remove the second element

```
string[] elements = templine.Split
        (space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where((s, i) => i != 1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

After your code above:

```
elements = elements.Take(1).Concat(elements.Skip(2)).ToArray();
```

---

One thing I want to point out: `Take` and `Skip` will not throw errors even if the original `elements` is too short; they'll simply produce empty `IEnumerable`s (which can be safely concatenated, and whose methods can be safely called).